# nscd as a system service: how do I get that?

Tags: services

Installing Guix (the package manager) in my Ubuntu 21.10

The Guix manual [says](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Application-Setup.html), among other things, that the system should be running a service called "nscd"

How do I get such a service ?

What do I have to install, exaclty ?

And How do I configure it ?

Thanks

Comment: `nscd` is the [Name Service Caching Daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/nscd.8.html). If you would like to install it, it's a simple `sudo apt install nscd` 

Comment: why the snarky smiley ? How was I supposed to know ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nscd` is in Ubuntu's `universe` repository.

To install it, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nscd
```